# Saving Multiple Files At Once

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been trying to figure out how to use the `SaveFileDialog` function in c# to save more than one file at a time.

The basic idea is, after the user has set parameters for a .cfg file, the user types out a set of serial numbers for which to save the configuration as. Then a `SaveFileDialog` is called allowing the user to save the one .cfg file under the names of the serial numbers the user listed.

Is this possible to do? Do you need to put the function into a loop, or is there another way to achieve this goal?

the .cfg file is set up like:

timezone=1

auto_DST=1

location=0

alarm_time=21

alarm_seconds_P=0

etc.

Here is what I have so far for saving that file:

```
List<Parameter> _paramList = new List<Parameter>();
List<Information> _infoList = new List<Information>();
           saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
           saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
           saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".CFG";
           saveFileDialog1.FileName = ( "config_" + txtParamValue.Text);
           saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Configuration files (*.CFG)|*.CFG|All files (*.*)|*.*";


           if ( saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog( ) == DialogResult.OK )
           {
               using ( StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter( saveFileDialog1.FileName ) )
               {
                   foreach (Parameter p in _paramList)
                   {
                       String name = p.ParameterName.Trim();
                       String val = p.ParameterValue.Trim();
                       foreach (Information i in _infoList)
                       {
                           if (p.ParameterName.Trim() == i.SimpleName)
                           {
                               name = i.InfoName;
                               if (i.InputChoice == "1")
                               {
                                   if (p.ParameterValue == "On")
                                       val = "1";
                                   else
                                       val = "0";
                               }
                               break;
                           }
                           else if (p.ParameterName.Trim() == i.InfoName)
                           {
                               if (p.ParameterValue == "On")
                                   val = "1";
                               else
                                   val = "0";
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                       if (name == "location" && val != location_update)
                       {
                           name = "location_update";
                       }
                       objWriter.WriteLine(name + "=" + val);
                   }
                   objWriter.Close();
               }
           }
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the structure of . cfg file? Also, I need the code information about _paramList and infoList, it will be better for me to solve your problem.

Comment: Consider breaking up this code into several smaller methods with more clearly-defined purposes. In general, each method should do only one thing and do it well. This method does at least three things: get save path from user, parse config options to text, and write the text to file.

Comment: A suggestion: don't use a SaveFileDialog, but a [FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog). Ask for a folder once, and then generate all your files in that folder, using whatever name you want for each.

Comment: The thing is I wish the generate multiple files at once, not one at a time, how would I specifically do that with either Dialog?